# Multi-res Icon use in VB6

Tags: windows, forms, button, vb6, icons

I have some multi-res icons containing 32x32, 48x48, and 128x128 versions. Currently, when assigning an icon to a button, it uses the 48x48 version because it's the first in the stack.

Since automatic resizing functions are ran when the resolution changes or if the screen rotates, sometimes it would be more ideal to use a different version like 32x32.

Is there a way, in VB6, to take advantage of the multiple versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the best approach is to only have one icon image per icon file. If you expect the icon to show as a 16x16 then provide a .ico file with a 16x16 icon in (say) 8-bit colour. That way VB has to use the icon you provide. It may mean you end up with a few file versions (16x16, 32x32) of the same icon but it makes life much easier

Comment: So as a direct answer to my question, the answer is no. The method you describe is of course doable though. It's just unfortunate and not as dynamic.